# How to concatenate NSNumbers and keep the locale format?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a calculator like. Every time I press one of the number buttons of the calculator, I would like to have the label displaying the input, to concatenate the new input to the display.

Let's say I press `1` then `2` then `5` and the label displays `125`. So far I was converting each number into a string and was appending them one after one. But I would like to make it "localized". So that if the locale is US, for `1,256.43` it display `1,256.43`. If the locale is FR, it displays `1 256,43`.

For that I was doing the same than before but to convert the number to string I was using a `NSNumberFormatter`. The problem is when I get the string `1 256` and I convert it into double (to then use the formatter) with `NSString(string: "1 256").doubleValue` I get `1` and not `1 256`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Don't convert back and forth, keep the number and convert to string for display

Comment: yes but what about displaying in real time the user input?

Comment: On each user input add to the number and then convert to string for display (if you want to keep another string behind the scenes without formatting for conversion of user input to a number that would work)

Comment: ok thanks. But the process to convert to a string in order to concatenate the numbers is mandatory or there is another solution?

Comment: You don't need to concatenation the numbers with a string, but it's probably the simplest code

Comment: What would be another (better?) solution?

Comment: Mathematically you can keep track of the tens digit and multiply and add each time a new number is added, not sure about other techniques as I've never considered / looked into approaches

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I never thought of it like that. That's what I'm gonna use. Seems proper.